# How do I show memory use graphically in the Xfce panel?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, xfce-panel

Xubuntu has a nice way of showing network data flow in the panel; put the Network Monitor in the panel and choose the network interface.

I know that Gnome has a similar feature in its System Monitor http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/11/ubuntu-tips-graphical-monitoring-for-processes-memory-load-average-and-disk-usage/ - but is there an Xfce equivalent?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just like Network Monitor, you have [System Load Monitor](https://launchpad.net/xfce4-systemload-plugin), this can show you the CPU, RAM and swap usage on the Xfce panel, and even the uptime.

[image: Example of the System Load Monitor with his configurations]

Comment: I didn't notice at first that the indicator itself was at the bottom of that image! Commenting here in case it helps other as inattentive as me :) Also, it's worth noting that this indicator only shows instantaneous values, not temporal graph like gnome's.

Comment: You might have to install it through `sudo apt-get install xfce4-systemload-plugin`, as I did on Mint.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a multifunctional system monitor applet, the installation is described here: [Does XFCE/Xubuntu have a system monitor panel applet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230471/does-xfce-xubuntu-have-a-system-monitor-panel-applet)