# Does XFCE/Xubuntu have a system monitor panel applet?

Tags: xubuntu, software-recommendation, xfce, xfce-panel

Gnome has a system monitor panel applet that can be seen even when all your windows are maximized:

[image]

Is there anything similar for Xubuntu / XFCE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install **[Multiload-ng](https://github.com/udda/multiload-ng)** or **[XFCE4-hardware-monitor-plugin](https://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-hardware-monitor-plugin)** as **all-in-one** solution. Also some separate solutions are in the **[xfce4-goodies](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/start#external_plugins)** package.

Actually, after building **Multiload-ng** correctly on XFCE desktop environment, there will be three apps from this package:

- Standalone app (has its own window, not embedded in any panel)
- Panel plugin (version of your desktop environment is automatically detected during build)
- Standard system tray app

So, you can use **Multiload-ng-systray** version even if your panel is not supported or you can not resolve some panel-specific dependencies (in such case remove **--disable-autostart** option during build).

### Installing Multiload-ng

Update your OS:

```shell
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Install dependencies (**depends on your system, check for warnings and errors during build**).
Tested on:

- Linux Mint XFCE Edition 20.1 x86_64 (XFCE 4.14)

```shell
sudo apt install git autotools-dev automake libtool intltool libgtk2.0-dev xfce4-panel-dev
```

- Linux Mint XFCE Edition 20.2 x86_64 (XFCE 4.16)

```shell
sudo apt install git autotools-dev automake libtool intltool libgtk2.0-dev libxfce4panel-2.0-dev
```

Clone source code:

```shell
git clone https://github.com/udda/multiload-ng
```

Build (**check for warnings and errors**):

```shell
cd ~/multiload-ng
./autogen.sh
./configure --disable-autostart
make
```

Install:

```shell
sudo make install
```

### Installing XFCE4-hardware-monitor-plugin

Update your OS:

```shell
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Install dependencies (**depends on your system, check for warnings and errors during build**).
Tested on:

- Linux Mint XFCE Edition 20.1 x86_64 (XFCE 4.14)

```shell
sudo apt install git libgtkmm-2.4-dev libgnomecanvasmm-2.6-dev libgtop2-dev libxfce4ui-1-dev build-essential libgtk2.0-dev xfce4-panel-dev intltool
```

Clone source code:

```shell
git clone https://git.xfce.org/archive/xfce4-hardware-monitor-plugin/
```

Build (**check for warnings and errors**):

```shell
cd ~/xfce4-hardware-monitor-plugin/
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/usr
make all
```

Install:

```shell
sudo make install
```

The screenshot below also includes **xfce4-weather-plugin** and **xfce4-datetime-plugin** from official repo.

[image: XFCE Multiload-ng XFCE4-hardware-monitor-plugin]

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Multiload-ng](https://udda.github.io/multiload-ng/), it is a bit old but it works on Xubuntu 20.04.
You will need to compile it yourself tho.

Answer (score 1):

Sure there are.

System Load Monitor, CPU Graph and Network Monitor are panel plugins of Xfce. They can be installed as dependencies by installing xfce4-goodies package. And you add the panel items by first right-clicking on panel or by using Panel dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to compile by yourself, you can download multiload-ng focal (20.04) binaries to a 22.04 system.  It works on my Xubuntu 22.04 desktop.  But note that there will be no security updating for these packages.

Download `xfce4-multiload-ng-plugin_1.5.2+git20210103-1~webupd8~focal2_amd64.deb` and `multiload-ng-common_1.5.2+git20210103-1~webupd8~focal2_all.deb` from PPA first:

- [https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/test/+build/20999673](https://launchpad.net/%7Enilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/test/+build/20999673)

Then install them:

```
sudo dpkg -i multiload-ng-common_1.5.2+git20210103-1~webupd8~focal2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i xfce4-multiload-ng-plugin_1.5.2+git20210103-1~webupd8~focal2_amd64.deb
```

Also install missing dependencies:

```
sudo apt install -f
```

After the installation, you will see Multiload-ng item in "Add New Items" from "Panel Preferences":

[image: Multiload-ng item]