# Can I configure XFCE or LXDE to look like this GNOME panel?

Tags: 20.04, xfce, lxde, dock, system-monitor

Can I configure XFCE or LXDE (the lightweight desktops) to look like this GNOME panel?

[image]

Note:

- "dock-to-panel" on the left that shows favorite apps
- starting apps not from the favorites adds them there temporarily
- currently running apps are underlined
- no separate list of currently running apps
- "System Monitor" to the right shows CPU, RAM and network usage histories.

Comment: You've not said what release (LXDE is GTK2 & thus *deprecated* using mostly unsupported libraries now) but Xfce allows almost limitless tweaking and adjusting (my own Xfce setup is based on the various features I liked in KDE, Unity (7), GNOME (2 & 3) & more.. My LXQt setup is based on my Xfce setup though as I couldn't have multiple panels on the same side of screen it's somewhat simpler ... LXDE was long ago) ... also LXDE is lightweight if using GTK2 apps, but that's mostly lost if using GTK3 or Qt5 apps which most of us use these days.

Comment: @guiverc 20.04 (edited, thanks for the reminder)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This answer is for XFCE

For the menu, add the whiskermenu plugin. You can change the icon to make it look like a grid.

For the dock, install [xfce4-docklike-plugin](https://gitlab.xfce.org/panel-plugins/xfce4-docklike-plugin), and add it to the panel. There is a PPA, so that you won't have to compile it yourself.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xubuntu-dev/extras
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xfce4-docklike-plugin
```

[image: docklike-plugin]

You can add a [system monitor plugin](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230471/does-xfce-xubuntu-have-a-system-monitor-panel-applet) to the panel (you can download prebuild .deb packages from [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Enilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8/+packages?field.name_filter=multiload-ng&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=focal)). Plugins for calendar, network, sound, and power are already available in XFCE.

Finally, change the color of the panel in the panel settings.